# How to stop SQL script execution for PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is DDL script in PostgreSQL that creates tables.

For example, if first table exists,
**How to stop SQL script execution for PostgreSQL (within script)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to abort a script based on a condition you can do that using a `DO` block that raises an error:

```
do
$$
declare 
  l_count integer;
begin

  select count(*)
     into l_count
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_name = 'foobar'
    and table_schema = 'public';

  if (l_count > 0) then 
     raise exception 'Table foobar already exists!';
  end if;
end;
$$
```

This requires that your SQL client will abort a script if an error occurs.

---

Another option is to change your script such that it doesn't do anything if the table already exists by using `create table if not exists ....`.

But that depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The idea was: there is no need to run whole script if the first table already exists. That is doing only simplest and quickest db initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 'Step 1' as step;

DO $$
  BEGIN
    assert (SELECT 'B'::text) = 'A'::text, 'Expected A';
  END;
$$;

SELECT 'Step 2' as step;
```

Returns:

```
ERROR:  Expected A
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at ASSERT
SQL state: P0004
```

You can use any type to compare assert with, not just text, apparently.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL database run each query in apparted process. You will need find out the process number. I use pg_activity, but you can run:

```
SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

once you found the PID you can kill it in shell:

```
kill $PID #or
kill -9 $PID
```

Comment: That is great piece of information, but that can't be inside SQL script, can it?

Comment: You don't need a kill on the command line `pg_cancel_backend()` (or even `pg_terminate_backend()`) will do the same thing

Comment: And please don't advertise `kill -KILL`

Comment: Do not use `kill -9` on queries it is strongly advised against.